# Has anyone gotten Electron to work in Tails?

Tags: electron

Has anyone here got "electron" to work under tails distribution? Or any other download binary for that matter? I tried downloading the x64 binary
from the official site, but it won't execute it:

```
amnesia@amnesia:~/Desktop/temp$ ./electron --help
bash: ./electron: No such file or directory
```

I tried putting "bash" in front of it and I get a similar error:

```
amnesia@amnesia:~/Desktop/temp$ bash ./electron --help
./electron: ./electron: cannot execute binary file
```

I then installed npm and tried to install it from there and I'm getting the following error:

```
electron@1.6.6 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron
node install.js

sh: 1: node: Permission denied
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! electron@1.6.6 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@1.6.6 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the electron package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls electron
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "electron"
npm ERR! cwd /home/amnesia/Desktop/prog
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/amnesia/Desktop/prog/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
amnesia@amnesia:~/Desktop/prog$
```

Does tails somehow prevent downloaded binaries from executing? Are
there certain directories that don't allow executables? I am confused.

I am using tails 2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get electron to work in tails by downloading the "ia32" version of the binary. For some reason the electron x64 binary does not work, even though I am using the 64-bit version of tails.